# Using find in jquery for extracting value of data-attr

Tags: jquery

I have a button

```
<button data-attr="x" data-attr-id="y" onclick="hello(this)">Hello</button>

function hello(value)
{
console.log(value);
}
```

This is returning me

```
<button data-attr="x" data-attr-id="y" onclick="hello(this)">Hello</button>
```

How can i extract value of data-attr and data-attr-id from value variable.....i think its using find method of jquery...can somebody help me to get the correct syntax...thanks

Comment: `$('button').data('attrId')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, there is no jQuery involved. You can do it with Javascript only by using `getAttribute` :

Just change :

```
console.log(value);
```

with :

```
console.log(value.getAttribute("data-attr"));
console.log(value.getAttribute("data-attr-id"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
function hello(element) {
    console.log($(element).data('attr-id'));
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/osekel/1/edit)

But as you use jQuery, it's recommended to separate the javascript from the HTML by binding using jQuery functions :

```
<button id=hop data-attr="x" data-attr-id="y">Hello</button>

<script>
    $('#hop').click(function(){
        console.log($(this).data('attr-id'));
    });
</script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ajudup/1/edit)